# Find k-th element in skiplist - explanation needed

Tags: algorithm, skip-lists

We're learning about skiplists at my university and we have to find k-th element in the skiplist. I haven't found anything about this in the internet, since skiplist in not really a popular data structure. W. Pugh in his original article wrote:
*Each element x has an index pos(x). We use this value in our invariants but do not store it. The index of the header is zero, the index of the first element is one and so on. Associated with each forward pointer is a measurement, fDistance, of the distance traversed by that pointer:

x→fDistance[i] = pos(x→forward[i]) – pos(x).

Note that the distance traversed by a level 1 pointer is always 1, so some storage economy is possible here at the cost of a slight increase in the complexity of the algorithms.*

```
SearchByPosition(list, k)
if k < 1 or k > size(list) then return bad-index
    x := list→header
    pos := 0
    -- loop invariant: pos = pos(x)
    for i := list→level downto 1 do
        while pos + x→fDistance[i] ≤ k do
            pos := pos + x→fDistance[i]
            x := x→forward[i]
return x→value
```

The problem is, I still don't get what is going on here. How do we know positions of elements without storing them? How do we calculate fDistance from pos(x) if we don't store it? If we go from the highest level of the skiplist, how do we know how many nodes on level 0 (or 1, the lowest one anyway) we skip this way?

Comment: Your title asks one question, but your final paragraph asks another. Can you please clarify what exactly you're interested in?

Comment: *"How do we calculate fDistance from pos(x) if we don't store it?"* From the code snippet, I'd say that `fDistance[i]` is stored. And you compute `pos(x)` from `fDistance`.

Comment: I modified the title to better show what I am asking for. Essentially I need to understand that algorithm and I think the answers to final questions will help me to do so.

Comment: I assume you're talking about an [Indexable skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're referring to how to find the `k`-th smallest (or largest) element in a skip list. This is a rather standard assumption I think, otherwise you have to clarify what you mean.

I'll refer to the GIF on wikipedia in this answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

[image]

Let's say you want to find the `k = 5` smallest element.

You start from the highest level (4 in the figure). How many elements would you skip from `30` to `NIL`? `6` (we also count the `30`). That's too much.

Go down a level. How many skipped from `30` to `50`? `2`: `30` and `40`.

So we reduced the problem to finding the `k = 5 - 2 = 3` smallest element starting at `50` on level `3`.

How many skipped from `50` to `NIL`? `4`, that's one too many.

Go down a level. How many skipped from `50` to `70`? `2`. Now find the `3 - 2 = 1` smallest element starting from `70` on level `2`.

How many skipped from `70` to `NIL`? `2`, one too many.

From `70` to `90` on level `1`? `1` (itself). So the answer is `70`.

So you need to store how many nodes are skipped for each node at each level and use that extra information in order to get an efficient solution. That seems to be what `fDistance[i]` does in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I finally understand it.

Answer (score -1):

The complete solution to the problem is provided here. Implementation in code is also given.

https://alexdremov.me/skip-list-indexation-and-kth-maximum/